# Get name and count of unique elements based on other column unique element

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Given the following sample dataframe:

```
df = 

Car       Country  

BMW       Germany
Tesla     USA
BMW       Germany
Mercedes  France
Tesla     USA
```

Based on unique values of column Country I want to get count and naming of column Car. Desired output:

```
Germany: 
BMW - 2

USA:
Telsa - 2

France:
Mercedes - 1
```

I have tried to play with pivot table but it was mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic use for `groupby`:

```py
df.groupby(["Country", "Car"]).size()
```